# Disable Histogram Scaling in ggplot2 ggridges

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

Please have a look at the following histograms of temperature for the various months of the year. I limit the temperature to 50+ degrees to purposefully force some of the the histograms to be *small*, for the colder months. Make note of months 1, 2, and 3, so small they barely register on the facet plot.

```
library(nycflights13)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
ggplot(weather %>% filter(temp > 50), aes(temp)) +
  geom_histogram() + 
  facet_wrap(~ as.factor(month))
```

This ggridges package is awesome. It also plots histograms. By default it scales the histograms such that the **y-values are relatively the same height. How do I disable this?** I know I have to somehow specify `height = ..stat_identity_count..` or `height = ..y..` but I've tried every conceivable combination and can't figure it out. In the plot below months 1, 2, and 3, which were barely noticeable above, have now been scaled to become enormous. I want the height of the y-axis to reflect actual counts of their respective histogram bins. Like the original facet wrap example.

```
library(ggridges)
ggplot(weather %>% filter(temp > 50), aes(x = temp, y = as.factor(month))) + 
  geom_density_ridges()
```

and I do understand it can often be easier to compare histograms by ..density.. vs absolute counts, but that's not what's desired in my current analysis.

Comment: This is the problem with `geom_histogram`, it doesn't actually plot histograms. By definition, histograms should be scaled so the area they cover sums to 1 like a proper density function. You should be able to compare histograms (and density functions) regardless of how many observations you have. They should not use "counts" as a y-axis for this reason. So what you're looking for isn't **really** a density plot. But it's still a reasonable request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `stat_density()`, using the `..count..` aesthetic instead of `..density..`:

```
ggplot(weather %>% filter(temp > 50),
       aes(x = temp, y = as.factor(month),
           group = as.factor(month), height = ..count..)) + 
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "density")
```

[image]